# Validate multiple forms on one page

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

New to jquery and trying to implement the validation plugin on a page with three forms. Submitting the first form works fine. In trying to submit the second form on the page(#loginForm) which requires only the username and password, the validation error appears in the form below looking for an email address. The forms --

```
<div class="newsTitle">REGISTER HERE</div>
<form id="registerForm" action="register.php" method="post" name="registerForm">
<b>Enter your email address</b><br>
<input type="text" id="emailrf" name="emailrf" size="30"  maxlength="64"><p>
<b>Full Name</b><br>
<input type="text" id="full_namerf" name="full_namerf" size="30" maxlength="64"><p>
Choose Username <span class="cap">( 4-24 characters )</span><br>
<input type="text" id="usernamerf" name="usernamerf" size="24" maxlength="24"><p>
Choose Password <span class="cap">( 6-12 characters )</span><br>
<input type="text" id="passwordrf" name="passwordrf" size="12" maxlength="12"><p>
<input type="hidden" name="formStatusregister" value="register">            
<input type="submit" id="rForm" class="subMit" name="srForm" value="REGISTER">
</form><p><br>

<div class="newsTitle">LOG IN PLEASE</div>
<form id="loginForm" action="register.php" method="post" name="loginForm">
<b class="red">username</b><br>
<input type="text" id="usernameli" name="usernameli" size="30"><p>
<b class="red">password</b><br>
<input type="password" id="passwordli" name="passwordli" size="30"><p>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes">  Remember Me 
 <input type="hidden" name="formStatuslogin" value="submitted"><br>             
<input type="submit" id="liForm" class="subMit" name="liForm" value="LOG-IN">
</form>

<p><br>
<div class="newsTitle">RETRIEVE YOUR LOG-IN INFO</div>
<form id="lostForm" action="register.php" name="lostForm" method="post">
Enter your email address and click SUBMIT.<p>
<input type="hidden" name="forgot" value="yes">
<b>email address</b><br>
<input type="text" id="emaill" name="emaill" size="30"><p>
<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="formStatuslost" value="forgot">
<input type="submit" id="lForm" name="lForm" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

and the js code:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {    
    $('#lostForm').validate({
        rules: {
            emaill: { 
            required:true,
            email:true
            }       
        }
});

$('#loginForm').validate({
rules: {        
    usernameli:{
        required:true,
        rangelength:[6,24]
        },          
        passwordli:{
        required:true
        }

}//--end rules

}); //--- END loginForm validate() ---//

$('#registerForm').validate({
rules: {
    emailrf: { 
    required:true,
    email:true,
            remote:{
                url:'check_email.php',
                type:'post'
                }
        },
        full_namerf: {
        required:true,
        letters:true
        },
        usernamerf:{
        required:true,
        rangelength:[6,24],
        remote:{
                url:'check_user.php',
                type:'post'
                }           
        },

        passwordrf:{
        required:true,
        rangelength:[6,12]
        }

}, //--end rules
messages:{
emailrf: {
remote:"This email is already registered"
},
usernamerf: {
remote:"Already in use - choose another"
}


} //end messages
}); //--- END registerForm validate() ---//

}); //--END ready---//
```

It acts as if the 2nd and 3rd forms are nested but they're not. What might be the issue?

Comment: Multiple elements with the same ID produces an unpredictable broken DOM. There's no way for jQuery to do anything with a page like that. Make a habit of validating your HTML before you do any troubleshooting. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same ID attribute on multiple inputs.

Each ID should be unique on the page. try prefixing the id with the name of the form to make it more unique eg:

```
<input type="text" id="registerformusername" name="username" size="24" value=""maxlength="24"><p>
```

That should help Jquery decide which elements are which

Edit: I've taken your altered code and put it into a simple html page. This seems to work fine . any validation errors only occur on the form that they belong to and only appear when the submit button for that form is clicked. Code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><br>
<div class="newsTitle">REGISTER HERE</div>
<form id="registerForm" action="register.php" method="post" name="registerForm">
<b>Enter your email address</b><br>
<input type="text" id="emailrf" name="emailrf" size="30"  maxlength="64"><p>
<b>Full Name</b><br>
<input type="text" id="full_namerf" name="full_namerf" size="30" maxlength="64"><p>
Choose Username <span class="cap">( 4-24 characters )</span><br>
<input type="text" id="usernamerf" name="usernamerf" size="24" maxlength="24"><p>
Choose Password <span class="cap">( 6-12 characters )</span><br>

<input type="text" id="passwordrf" name="passwordrf" size="12" maxlength="12"><p>
<input type="hidden" name="formStatusregister" value="register">            
<input type="submit" id="rForm" class="subMit" name="srForm" value="REGISTER">
</form><p><br>

<div class="newsTitle">LOG IN PLEASE</div>
<form id="loginForm" action="register.php" method="post" name="loginForm">
<b class="red">username</b><br>
<input type="text" id="usernameli" name="usernameli" size="30"><p>
<b class="red">password</b><br>
<input type="password" id="passwordli" name="passwordli" size="30"><p>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes">  Remember Me 
<input type="hidden" name="formStatuslogin" value="submitted"><br>             

<input type="submit" id="liForm" class="subMit" name="liForm" value="LOG-IN">
</form>

<p><br>
<div class="newsTitle">RETRIEVE YOUR LOG-IN INFO</div>
<form id="lostForm" action="register.php" name="lostForm" method="post">
Enter your email address and click SUBMIT.<p>
<input type="hidden" name="forgot" value="yes">
<b>email address</b><br>
<input type="text" id="emaill" name="emaill" size="30"><p>
<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="formStatuslost" value="forgot">
<input type="submit" id="lForm" name="lForm" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

<script>


$(document).ready(
function() {    
$('#lostForm').validate({
rules: {
    emaill: { 
    required:true,
    email:true
    }       
}
});

$('#loginForm').validate({
rules: {        
usernameli:{
required:true,
rangelength:[6,24]
},          
passwordli:{
required:true
}

}//--end rules

}); //--- END loginForm validate() ---//

$('#registerForm').validate({
rules: {
emailrf: { 
required:true,
email:true,
    remote:{
        url:'check_email.php',
        type:'post'
        }
},
full_namerf: {
required:true,
letters:true
},
usernamerf:{
required:true,
rangelength:[6,24],
remote:{
        url:'check_user.php',
        type:'post'
        }           
},

    passwordrf:{
    required:true,
    rangelength:[6,12]
    }

}, //--end rules
messages:{
emailrf: {
remote:"This email is already registered"
},
usernamerf: {
remote:"Already in use - choose another"
}


} //end messages
}); //--- END registerForm validate() ---//

}); //--END ready---//
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I had given them unique ID's initially and nothing worked. I have gone back to that based on the advice here and again, it doesn't work. The forms submit without any iput and/or the wrong input.

Comment: I believe the issue is the lack of fieldset tags

Comment: No, the validation plugin shouldn't need fieldset tabs. I've just tried the code that you posted and it works fine (gives validation errors if you don't fill in the fields) in Chrome and Firefox! Have you tried going to the javascript console and seeing if any errors are reported?

Comment: The code above does not work as is. Using the first form, enter info in the top three fileds and click to submit - the validation error messages appear on all three forms. I'm testing on Firefox/PC. I only got it working when I added the fieldset to all forms which also allowed the page to validate. Then, the error messages only appear on the form you are actually trying to submit.